# Selenium Web driver with Azure Web jobs

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-webjobs

i have written a C# selenium code which opens browser and takes the screenshot . Code is running fine in my local laptop but when i try to deploy the code on azure webjobs. code fails to run. It may be because of local system has chrome browser installed whereas it is missing from cloud. I have even included the chrome.exe file with my directory but not finding a success. i am stuck and tried many thing but not found a way to proceed .

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not supported by Azure Web App/Web Jobs currently. It's noted under Unsupported frameworks tags.

[Azure Web App sandbox:Unsupported frameworks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks)

> Other scenarios that are not supported:
>
> PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses
>   GDI+.

Comment: is there any other way to take the screenshot of webpage and code can be run on azure webjob.